# Mysql group by to produce one row

Tags: mysql, group-by, grouping

I have this query

```
SELECT IF( sort_order =1, title, NULL ) AS q1, IF( sort_order =2, title, NULL ) AS q2,
       IF( sort_order =3, title, NULL ) AS q3
FROM  `choice` 
WHERE  `question_id` =1101
```

that displays this result

```
    q1    q2       q3
Pollster  NULL     NULL

NULL      Snooper  NULL

NULL      NULL     The Tank
```

Is there a way to group or order that will give me this result

```
    q1    q2       q3
Pollster  Snooper  The Tank
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Just include aggregation functions:

```
SELECT max(IF( sort_order =1, title, NULL )) AS q1,
       max(IF( sort_order =2, title, NULL )) AS q2,
       max(IF( sort_order =3, title, NULL )) AS q3
FROM  `choice` 
WHERE  `question_id` = 1101;
```